# How to partially specialize function to invoke function with tuple elements as arguments

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I'm trying to call a function using an unpacked tuple, but I have hit an issue. My code relies on the ability to do a special case with the function when it is zero. This code does not work, but how would I accomplish this using valid c++?

```
//Initialize Recursion
template <class ret, class ... Ts>
ret templateHelpers::callFunctionFromTuple(ret (*function)(Ts...), std::tuple<Ts...> tuple) {
    return callFunctionFromTupleHelper<sizeof...(Ts), ret>(function, tuple);
}

//Recursively break down the tuple
template <int NumLeft, class ret, class ... ArgsF, class ... ArgsT, class ... Args>
ret templateHelpers::callFunctionFromTupleHelper(ret (*function)(ArgsF...), std::tuple<ArgsT...> tuple, Args... ts) {
    return callFunctionFromTuple<numLeft - 1, ret>(funcTs(function, std::tuple<Tuples...> tuple, std::get<NumLeft-1>(tuple) Ts... ts));
}

//Finally Call the Function
//TODO: fix the error. Partial specialization does not work, including that <0>
template <class ret, class ... ArgsF, class ... ArgsT, class ... Args>
ret templateHelpers::callFunctionFromTupleHelper<0>(ret (*function)(ArgsF...), std::tuple<ArgsT...> tuple, Args... ts) {
    return func(ts...);
}
```

PS I'm using VS2017

Comment: How would I accomplish that?

Comment: Write a class template with a `operator()`?

Comment: @user3117152 - See my answer.

Comment: Btw `std::apply` does exactly this, try looking into that when available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to unpack a `std::tuple` is to use `sdt::index_sequence`

```
#include<utility>
#include<tuple>

template<typename Ret, typename... Ts, size_t... I>
Ret callFunction_(Ret (*fn)(Ts...), std::tuple<Ts...> tup, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return fn(std::get<I>(tup)...);
}

template<typename Ret, typename... Ts, typename Tuple>
Ret callFunction(Ret (*fn)(Ts...), Tuple&& tup)
{
    return callFunction_(fn, std::forward<Tuple>(tup),
        std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<Tuple>>{}>{});
}
```

[Live](http://ideone.com/C1biQM)

And then no delegation to class templates is required :)

Comment: Great solution!  Just that it only works with rvalue tuple arguments,  you probably wanted to template that tuple argument as a full type template.  And then get the size seperately or use `make_index_sequence` as in the `std::apply` implementation here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply

Comment: @Curious Yeah that was definitely a oopsies on the rvalue reference, thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is no partial specialization of template functions in C++. Have your function defer to a class template which can be partially specialized.

```
namespace detail {
  template<...>
  struct callFunctionFromTupleImpl {
    static ret do_call(...) {
    }
  };

  // + more partial specializations
}

template <class ret, class ... Ts>
ret callFunctionFromTuple(ret (*function)(Ts...), std::tuple<Ts...> tuple) {
    return detail::callFunctionFromTupleHelperImpl<ret, Ts...>::do_call(function, tuple);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[In addition to what @StoryTeller said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44743731/5501675), since I wrote up a complete solution with perfect forwarding without knowing there was already a posted answer here it is

If you don't want to consider the [possible implementation from cppreference for std::apply](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply) and modify it to fit your program.  You would need to delegate invocation to a struct

```
#include <tuple>
#include <cassert>

namespace detail {
    template <int Size>
    struct InvokeHelper {
        template <typename Func, typename TupleType, typename... Args>
        static decltype(auto) apply(Func&& func, TupleType&& tup,
                                    Args&&... args) {
            constexpr auto tuple_size =
                std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<TupleType>>::value;
            return InvokeHelper<Size - 1>::apply(
                    std::forward<Func>(func),
                    tup,
                    std::forward<Args>(args)...,
                    std::get<tuple_size - Size>(
                        std::forward<TupleType>(tup)));
        }
    };
    template <>
    struct InvokeHelper<0> {
        template <typename Func, typename TupleType, typename... Args>
        static decltype(auto) apply(Func&& func, TupleType&&, Args&&... args) {
            return std::forward<Func>(func)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    };
} // namespace detail

template <typename Func, typename TupleType>
decltype(auto) invoke_tuple(Func&& func, TupleType&& tup) {
    constexpr auto tuple_size = std::tuple_size<std::decay_t<TupleType>>::value;
    return detail::InvokeHelper<tuple_size>::apply(
            std::forward<Func>(func), std::forward<TupleType>(tup));
}

int main() {
    auto tup = std::make_tuple(1, 2);
    assert(invoke_tuple([](int a, int b) { return a + b; }, tup) == 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also acheive the functionality you want using std::enable_if.  Apologies in advance if there are any typos since I won't be anywhere near a computer for the next few days.

```
template <std::size_t N, typename ret>
typename std::enable_if<N != 0, ret>::type f
(
)
{
    return f<N-1, ret>();
}

template <std::size_t N, typename ret>
typename std::enable_if<N == 0, ret>::type f
(
)
{
    return ret();
}
```

Comment: Probably due to bad formatting and having nothing to do with the question.

Comment: The question concerned ending recursion by partial specialization of a function template. As StoryTeller wrote, this is not possible. However, there are numerous solutions to the problem and my solution is absutely one of them. It appears in a lot of very professional grade code. Formatting should not be a factor and is not something I am going to defend here. It is the result of two decades of experience.

Comment: The main issue is that this code doesn't "invoke function with tuple elements as arguments", but just constructs a value of type `ret`, i.e. it isn't an answer. It should have been added as a comment, or had to invoke a function with tuple elements as arguments. Nobody questions the validity of `enable_if` approach here.

Comment: First, thankyou for being direct. But the questioner clearly understands those details and the question literally asked "My code relies on the ability to do a special case with the function when it is zero. This code does not work, but how would I accomplish this using valid c++?" Is this not exactly what my answer addressed? I believe my answer was a generic solution to the actual question rather than the title of the question.

Comment: While the questioner may or may not understand details, this is Q&A website, where questions and answers are supposed to be found and read by a lot of people. It's not safe to assume all readers can figure out the way to extend the approach to a full answer. That's why posting approaches instead of answers is discouraged. Such partial answers tend to get heavily downvoted over time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147572/discussion-between-michael-maniscalco-and-polkovnikov-ph).

Comment: I actually tried this but couldn't get it to compile correctly